# search in the list by keyword and category

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement a search by category and keyword, but the query returns an empty list. I know that you can make several methods for requests, but I would like to fit this into one method. Please tell me how to do this correctly

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
    User findByNickname(String nickname);
    User findByPhone(String phoneNumber);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE :filter LIKE CONCAT('%',:keyword,'%')",
            nativeQuery=true)
    List<User> findByKeyword(@Param("filter") String filter, 
                             @Param("keyword") String keyword);
  
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String index(Model model, Principal user,
                        String keyword, String filter){
        model.addAttribute("user",
                userService.findUserByNickname(user.getName()));
        if(keyword!=null){
            model.addAttribute("users",
                    userService.getUsersByKeyword(filter, keyword));
            return "admin/index";
        }
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
        return "admin/index";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
        <form th:action="@{/admin/users}" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="keyword">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="id"><label>ID</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="nickname"><label>NAME</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="phone"><label>PHONE</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="email"><label>EMAIL</label>
            <button type="submit">Go</button>
        </form>
```

Service:

```
public List<User> getUsersByKeyword(String filter, String keyword){
    return userRepository.findByKeyword(filter,keyword);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a specification: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Just let your repository extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>`:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>,
                                        JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

And query by specification:

```
String column = "myColumn"; // user-supplied
String value = "myValue"; // user-supplied

Specification<User> spec = (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
                               criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(column), "%" + value + "%");

var result = repo.findAll(spec);
```